# Why is the numbers not adding properly?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am currently finishing a [hackerrank](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/30-2d-arrays/problem) challenge. The solution I wrote works for half the test but fail for the other tests. I noticed that when manually adding the numbers, it does not equal to the expected answer. For example, in the test data below, I can't find any combinations that adds to the expected output.

I tried debugging it manually and using pdb but I do not recognize the problem.

Here is the test data :

```
1 1 1 0 0 0
0 1 0 0 0 0
1 1 1 0 0 0
0 9 2 -4 -4 0
0 0 0 -2 0 0
0 0 -1 -2 -4 0
```

Here is the expected output :

```
13
```

Here is the script :

```
#!/bin/python3

def get_hourglasses(array):
    hourglasses = list()
    row_list = list()

    # Extract rows
    for row in range(len(array)):
        for col in range(len(array[row])):
            try:
                to_append = [array[row][col], array[row][col+1], array[row][col+2]]
                row_list.append(to_append)
            except IndexError:
                break

    # Construct hourglass
    for row in range(len(row_list)):
        try:
            hourglass = [row_list[row], row_list[row+4], row_list[row+8]]
            hourglasses.append(hourglass)
        except:
            break

    return hourglasses

def get_maximum_hourglass_sum(array):
    hourglass_sums = list()
    hourglasses = get_hourglasses(array)

    # add all the hourglasses
    sums = int()
    for hourglass in hourglasses:
        hourglass_sums.append(sums)
        sums = 0
        for row in hourglass:
            sums += sum(row)

    return sorted(hourglass_sums)[-1]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    arr = []

    for _ in range(6):
        arr.append(list(map(int, input().rstrip().split())))

    print(get_maximum_hourglass_sum(arr))
```

Comment: Looks to me like the result should be `12`. The hourglass with `9` in the center.

Comment: Why do you think the expected result is 13?

Comment: The test said it is 13 @Barmar

Comment: It's kind of bugging me, it seems the script is correct, so it's either the way Python adds or the test is outdated. I can't find the problem!

Comment: Thank you @Barmar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with @Barmar, and thus I understand your misunderstanding.

However, correct me if I'm wrong but I have some doubts about your `get_maximum_hourglass_sum` function because it seems to me that you are actually taking all of the middle row of an hourglass into account (instead of taking only the middle point)

PS : I ran your code on hackerank and I failed most of the test due to RunTimeError though

Comment: Oh, you know that's probably where I got wrong. I didn't even think that you need to take the middle only on the middle row.

Comment: okay so i fixed the script, after only calculating the minimum, another problem occur, wierdly after moving the append line to the bottom of the loop, it fixed itself.

Comment: You welcome ! If you want to improve the execution time and need some help, feel free to message me. In fact SPOILER ----------------------------> you can calculate the sum within the second loop at least. There is some way to go faster but I don't think it is needed. :)

Comment: I think I would want to figure it out myself. It's quite rewarding. I asked for help just now but it doesn't really feel good. I missed a simple mistake.